# Pascal. How to insert a word in the middle of a line

Tags: pascal

Fill the screen with green. Enter a string from the keyboard. Print a line in the center of the screen, inserting the specified word in the middle of it.I need help !I need the word inserted in the middle of the line. How do I do this?

```
 uses crt;
    var s1,s2:string;
    k,p:integer;
    count:boolean;
    begin
      Window(0,0,100,100);
      textbackground (green);
      textcolor(black);
      clrscr;
      write('Enter a string and a word: ');
      readln(s1);
      readln(s2);
      clrscr;
      gotoXY(45,13);
      p:=length(s1);
        for k:= 1 to p do
          begin
          if ((s1[k]= ' ') and (count=false)) then
            begin
              write(' ',s2);
              count:=true;
            end;
            write(s1[k]);
          end;
        if count <> true then
        begin
          write(' ',s2);
        end;
        gotoXY(1,30);
    end.
```

Comment: Welcom to SO.  I'm afraid it isn't a homework-doing service - we help with specific programming points where you get stuck.  So where are you stuck, exactly?  You seem to have to main components of a solution - using the Crt unit, gotoxy, so what's your problem?  Btw, are you using FreePascal + Lazarus or another Pascal?

Comment: Hi i know this, but I can't figure out how to write this in the code.And I thought maybe I could get some help here.I use pascalABC

Comment: So, did **you** write the code in your q or did you get it from somewhere?  And please answer my query about which Pascal you're using.

Comment: I wrote it, but I was given a new task for this code. Pascal 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the details of pascalABC but it presumably has a Crt unit which gives you some control over the screen and where items are written to it, using GotoXY, followed by Write.

So you basically need to address these tasks:

1. Find the screen width as a number of characters.  Or, your Crt unit may provide you with a way of specifying the screen width, e.g. as part of creating an on-screen window.
2. You know the length of your string (e.g. from Length(MyString)).  So to place the string in the horizontal centre of the screen, you need to calculate the necessary X value to specify in a call to GotoXY.  It is simply

   `X := (ScreenWidth - Length(MyString)) div 2;`

   Same for the Y value.  Of course, the X value may not be exactly correct if (ScreenWidth - Length(MyString) is an odd number rather than an even one, but you can't do anything about that.
3. Once you've used GotoXY to position the cursor, just do

   `Write(MyString);`
4. If your Crt unit allows you to specify the font, you'll probably get a better visual result if you specify a fixed-point font like Courier (or Cyrillic equivalent).
5. Finally, you need to call ReadLn at the very end of your code so that the program waits for you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, otherwise the console window the program display in will just vanish, if it works like FreePascal's Crt unit.